# Destiny 2 expansions question from a returning player on PS4

Tags: ps4, destiny-2

I was a hardcore Destiny player, then when Destiny 2 came out I bought it at day 1, but after completing the campaign I left it.

Now, I realized that for PS plus users, Destiny 2 is now downloadable for free, so although I have the physical copy I downloaded the digital version... and now come my questions:

1. Does this digital version last forever or does it expires at some point?
2. In the map screen I see the link to buy the Forsaken expansion, but once I click I cannot buy the expansion, instead I see a screen in which the game itself is shown... what does it mean? (do I have to buy the previous expansions in order to unlock the latest one?)
3. If I have (or I decide) to buy the first 2 expansions, can I buy the expansion pass to have both or do I have to buy them separately? (Because it's super weird to me to see that the pass is sold for 19.99, while each expansion has the same price... I mean who is the idiot that would spend 39,80 when he can spend just 19.90... so maybe I don't get something)*

   - Prices are in euro and refers to the European ps store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be voted to break into three questions, but I'll address the points anyway.

1) You will have access to the PS Plus version of the game as long as you are subscribed to PS Plus. If your subscription expires, you will not be able to play the game until you are re-subscribed. As long as you are subscribed you will own the game.

2) Since the release of Forsaken, the purchase options have changed. You now need to buy the complete game with all the expansions, optionally with an expansion pass for year 2. Or you will need to buy the expansions individually.

2a) You do not need to buy Curse of Osiris and Warmind to play Forsaken, but if you buy the game pack, you'll get these anyway. If you have an older character, you will be given a Level Booster, to boost your character to level 30, so you can begin Forsaken. However you will not be able to complete the Curse of Osiris or Warmind campaigns.

3) You buy them individually or purchase the Year One Expansion Pass.

Comment: You sure about 2a?  From what I gathered, I couldn't (on PC) just buy Forsaken - the screen informed me that I had to have the first 2 xpacs before I could also buy Forsaken.

Comment: Yes, I haven't worded that clearly. You can buy Curse of Osiris and Warmind individually. Forsaken is bundled as part of the whole game. I think they prefer you to purchase the bundle. https://eu.shop.battle.net/en-gb/family/destiny-2

Comment: Interestingly, on a PC you can get away with the "free" download of Destiny 2 (until the 19th of November 2018), and then just buy the "Forsaken" DLC, which includes all of Curse of Osiris and Warmind now.